# How to avoid variable conflicts while using output buffering

Tags: php, output-buffering

I'm writing a function, as a learning excercise, to combine and minify css files and php files that output generated css.

Everything is fine looping through the css files but as soon it tries to push the string returned from the output buffer from the php file the array becomes an int. var_dump() yields this:

```
int(5)
```

I've also tried concatenating the strings; it works fine again until it get's to the php file, then everything previous in the string becomes 4. Like so:

```
4/*
* Home: Appointment Grid
*/
.difAppointmentGrid {
    margin: 2rem 0;
    font-family: "Lato" !important;
    box-shadow: -4px 4px 16px 4px hsla( 240, 0%, 0%, 0.1 );
}
. . .
```

This is an example of what I'm doing in the styles.php file:

```
. . . 
.difAppointmentGrid header div h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1.5rem 0;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
<?php
for ( $h3 = 1, $o = 0.40; $h3 <= 4; ++$h3, $o += 0.20 )
{
    $rule = '.difAppointmentGrid header div:nth-child('.$h3.') h3 {'."\n\t".
            'background-color: hsla( 223, 63%, 22%, '.$o.' );'."\n".
            '}'."\n";
    echo $rule;
}
?>
.dif_grid {
    display: flex;
}
. . .
```

This is the function:

```
function styles_init()
{
    $path = __DIR__ . '/aggregate.min.css';
    if ( is_writable( $path ) )
    {
        $r = array();
        foreach( array_filter( glob( __DIR__ . '/modules/*.*' ), 'is_file' ) as $file )
        {
            $fn = pathinfo( $file );
            if ( $fn['extension'] == 'php' || $fn['extension'] == 'css'  )
            {
                ob_start();
                include( $file );
                $x = ob_get_flush();
                $r[] = $x;
            }
        }
        $c = implode( "\n\n", $r );
        //$c = str_replace( array( ' {', ': ', ', ' ), array( '{', ':', ',' ) , str_replace( array( "\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    ' ), '', preg_replace( '!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $c ) ) );

        $f = fopen( $path, 'wb' );
        fwrite( $f, $c );
        fclose( $f );
    }
}
```

The weirdest part is no errors are actually thrown when array_pushing/concatenating. I don't even know exactly what question to ask because I can't actually figure out what's going wrong. I've also messed around with headers, character encoding,  different ob functions, and casting ob_get_flush to string out of desperation.

Solution:

```
function get_include_output($file)
{
    ob_start();
    include( $file );
    return ob_get_flush();
}
function styles_init()
{
    $path = __DIR__ . '/aggregate.min.css';
    if ( is_writable( $path ) )
    {
        $r = array();
        foreach( array_filter( glob( __DIR__ . '/modules/*.*' ), 'is_file' ) as $file )
        {
            $fn = pathinfo( $file );
            if ( $fn['extension'] == 'php' || $fn['extension'] == 'css'  )
            {
                $r[] = get_include_contents( $file );
            }
        }
        $c = implode( "\n\n", $r );
        //$c = str_replace( array( ' {', ': ', ', ' ), array( '{', ':', ',' ) , str_replace( array( "\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    ' ), '', preg_replace( '!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $c ) ) );

        $f = fopen( $path, 'wb' );
        fwrite( $f, $c );
        fclose( $f );
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you dumping?  Also `$r[] = $x` is better than using `array_push()` here.

Comment: @GentlemanMax I just tried it with $r[ count( $r ) ] = $x; and it resulted in the same behavior.  I've just been using var_dump() and error_log() to get the values as it loops.

My suspicion is that this is stemming from some aspect of output buffering that I am unaware of.

Comment: You don't need the `count($r)` bit, regardless, you're doing `var_dump($r)` right after `array_push()`? Have you tried with `ob_get_clean()`?

Comment: [`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) is really supposed to return new number of elements in the array

Comment: @GentlemanMax Yes, regarding both. I actually wrote the function with with ob_get_clean(), however I switched it to ob_get_flush() as the later worked more reliably, i.e., ob_get_clean() would only return the contents of style.php, ignoring any *.css files; whereas ob_get_flush() returns the contents of both file types.

Comment: Using output buffering and include like this is a really poor way to implement this. You should define a function that returns the string. Then you can call it in a loop and concatenate the results.

Comment: Is it possible the `.php` file that you're including assigns to `$r` somewhere? This is why functions are better, they isolate the variable scope.

Comment: @Barmar Interesting. I was operating under the impression that output buffering had it's own implicit scope. That isn't mentioned anywhere in the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).

Comment: Output buffering has nothing to do with scope, all it does is save the output. Nothing is mentioned because they're unrelated concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the PHP file you're including is using the variable `$r`, so it's overwriting your variable with a number. You can avoid variable conflicts by wrapping the code that gets the result of including the file as a string in a function, since this will have its own variable scope.

```
function get_include_output($file) {
    ob_start();
    include($file);
    return ob_get_flush();
}
```

Then change your code to:

```
       if ( $fn['extension'] == 'php' || $fn['extension'] == 'css'  )
        {
            $x = get_include_contents($file);
            array_push( $r, $x );
        }
```

Comment: This seems likely; I didn't realize that php doesn't have block level scoping. I'll have to verify this when I'm back in the office on monday.

If this is the cause then that implies output buffering does not provide scope encapsulation. Is that correct?

Comment: Remember that one of the common uses of include files is to set variables. If the include file were in its own scope, it couldn't do that.

Comment: I've only just started learning PHP, so this is all really useful information. Thanks.